# Azure DevOps - How to download a file from repo using SSIS

Tags: ssis, azure-devops

I am looking to create a SSIS package which downloads a file from an Azure DevOps GIT repository.

The file is a excel spread sheet.

The SSIS package should download this file in a local directory which can then be used for further processing.

Is this possible to achieve using SSIS?

Comment: May I know how's the status of this? Does below work around is achievable for you? Free to leave comment below if you still has puzzle or any question.

Comment: I didn't try the workaround suggested, Thanks @MerlinLiang-MSFT

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible to achieve using SSIS?

I'm afraid, no, this could not be achieved via `SSIS` until now. Because what is available in Azure devops is `build` and `deploy` SSIS package. We haven't support to **run** SSIS package in `Azure devops pipeline` at this time.

---

At present, you can make use `Azure Data Factory`, which is the one service of Azure. See this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-invoke-ssis-package-ssis-activity).

But also, as far as I know, it does not support activity of **copy file via SSIS**. And if you want the excel file can be further processing with SSIS, you may consider to use [Azure file copy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-file-copy?view=azure-devops) to copy the excel file to Azure blob:

[image]

Comment: Could you please help me to download a file [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63407273/download-a-file-from-azure-devops-server-writes-wrong-data-to-the-file). Your help is greatly appreciated. @Merlin Liang - MSFT

Answer (score 0):

You can do just about anything you want in Azure Devops using either the Powershell release template or the Run Powershell on Remote Machines release template. The only catch here is setting up WinRM on the remote servers, opening ports/firewall settings, using X509 self-signed certs if you want to do this over SSL, WinRM listeners, setting up trusted hosts, etc. etc. It took me two months to finally get WinRM setup and working correctly from Azure Devops (in my case that included setting up a special security group policy to allow the WinRM services to run unimpeded on the remote machines joined to the domain). Once you have WinRM working though, you can have Azure Devops drive anything that you could script with Powershell so the effort was worth it for me. If you embark on this adventure, take the time to write some powershell test scripts that call Invoke-command to test all of the WinRM security features I mention above, this will save you a lot of time with troubleshooting a remote connection over WinRM.