# Download a file from azure devops server writes wrong data to the file

Tags: c#, html, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to download a SQL file from azure devops server using the API, but an html page source code with signout link is copied to the file.

**C# Code**

```
 var personalaccesstoken = "wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwy47b7ugkz32bubi64bw7fqdyfpa";
        var url = $"https://dev.azure.com/OrgTest/ABCProject/_apis/git/repositories/e9e2f082-99999iii-dummy-869b0bcc737a/items?path=/Versiondata/Datfile/ABC.sql&includeContent=true&api-version=5.1";
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.UserAgent = "VSTS-Get";
        
        request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer " + personalaccesstoken);
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "GET";
        

        request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
       var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream()) 
        {
            using (var filestream = File.Create(System.IO.Path.Combine("D:\\testFolder\\", "ABC.sql")))
            {
                responseStream.CopyTo(filestream);
            }
        }
```

Unfortunately I am getting below html content in file

**Content Output file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

    
    

<html lang="en-US">
<head><title>
    
            Azure DevOps Services | Sign In
        
</title><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11;&#32;IE=10;&#32;IE=9;&#32;IE=8" />
    <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="/favicon.ico"/>

    <link data-bundlelength="508967" data-bundlename="commoncss" data-highcontrast="/_static/tfs/M172_20200708.14/_cssbundles/HighContrast/vss-bundle-commoncss-vbprQZmxiRGQT6OOu7QI7gB_rewyS40Ce_ulm1Fh3rQQ=" data-includedstyles="jQueryUI-Modified;Core;Splitter;PivotView" href="/_static/tfs/M172_20200708.14/_cssbundles/Default/vss-bundle-commoncss-v18eOGnLpZpVm7mtRF63HJdB9wzrq2LZpAxko9qNRfdY=" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-bundlelength="116304" data-bundlename="viewcss" data-highcontrast="/_static/tfs/M172_20200708.14/_cssbundles/HighContrast/vss-bundle-viewcss-vv48rOLU2KepPSTALtsmN5-gXtibzGGwjVnS2QIkrRI4=" data-includedstyles="VSS.Controls" href="/_static/tfs/M172_20200708.14/_cssbundles/Default/vss-bundle-viewcss-vDH9dOETFqT44jZvM_rX-2sP7DneEj_u8KJJ1u7Bcr3I=" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!--UxServices customizations -->
    
    <link href="/_static/tfs/M172_20200708.14/_content/Authentication.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
</head>

<body class="platform">

    <script type="text/javascript"> var __vssPageContext = {"webContext":{"user":{"id":"aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa","name":"Anonymous","email":"","uniqueName":"TEAM FOUNDATION\\Anonymous"},"host":{"id":"7d0cc8e9-39e8-4313-9ff3-23ace0f8f4cf","name":"TEAM FOUNDATION","uri":"https://spsprodweu4.vssps.visualstudio.com/","relativeUri":"/","hostType":"deployment","scheme":"https","authority":"spsprodweu4.vssps.visualstudio.com"}},"moduleLoaderConfig":{"baseUrl":"/_static/tfs/M172_20200708.14/_scripts/TFS/min/","paths":{"Profile/Scripts/Resources":"en-US","VSS/Resources":"en-US","Account/Scripts/Resources":"en-US","UserManagement/Scripts/Resources":"en-US","Authentication/Scripts/Resources":"en-US"},"map":{},"contributionPaths":{"VSS":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M172_20200708.14/_scripts/TFS/min/VSS","pathType":"default"},"VSS/Resources":{"value":"en-US","pathType":"resource"},"q":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M172_20200708.14/_scripts/TFS/min/q","pathType":"default"},"knockout":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M172_20200708.14/_scripts/TFS/min/knockout","pathType":"default"},"mousetrap":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M172_20200708.14/_scripts/TFS/min/mousetrap","pathType":"default"},"mustache":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M172_20200708.14/_scripts/TFS/min/mustache","pathType":"default"},"react":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M172_20200708.14/_scripts/TFS/min/react.15.3","pathType":"default"},"react-dom":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M172_20200708.14/_scripts/TFS/min/react-dom.15.3","pathType":"default"},"react-transition-group":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M172_20200708.14/_scripts/TFS/min/react-transition-group.15.3","pathType":"default"},"jQueryUI":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M172_20200708.14/_scripts/TFS/min/jQueryUI","pathType":"default"},"jquery":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M172_20200708.14/_scripts/TFS/min/jquery","pathType":"default"},"OfficeFabric":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M172_20200708.14/_scripts/TFS/min/OfficeFabric","pathType":"default"},"tslib":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M172_20200708.14/_scripts/TFS/min/tslib","pathType":"default"},"@uifabric":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M172_20200708.14/_scripts/TFS/min/@uifabric","pathType":"default"},"VSSUI":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M172_20200708.14/_scripts/TFS/min/VSSUI","pathType":"default"}},"shim":{"jquery":{"deps":[],"exports":"jQuery"}},"waitSeconds":30},"coreReferences":{"stylesheets":[{"url":"/_static/tfs/M172_20200708.14/_cssbundles/Default/vss-bundle-ext-core-css-vQ8Us1s7UaJe7EYaHu4abPhUIoy4VkQeq0UCGlmbyyiE=","highContrastUrl":null,"isCoreStylesheet":true}],"scripts":[{"identifier":"JQuery","url":"/_static/3rdParty/_scripts/jquery-2.2.4.min.js","fallbackUrl":null,"fallbackCondition":null,"isCoreModule":true},{"identifier":"JQueryXDomain","url":"/_static/3rdParty/_scripts/jquery.xdomainrequest.min.js","fallbackUrl":null,"fallbackCondition":null,"isCoreModule":true},{"identifier":"Promise","url":"/_static/tfs/M172_20200708.14/_scripts/TFS/min/promise.js","fallbackUrl":null,"fallbackCondition":null,"isCoreModule":true},{"identifier":"GlobalScripts","url":"/_static/tfs/M172_20200708.14/_scripts/TFS/min/global-scripts.js","fallbackUrl":null,"fallbackCondition":null,"isCoreModule":true},{"identifier":"LoaderFixes","url":"/_static/tfs/M172_20200708.14/_scripts/TFS/pre-loader-shim.min.js","fallbackUrl":null,"fallbackCondition":null,"isCoreModule":false},{"identifier":"AMDLoader","url":"/_static/3rdParty/_scripts/require.min.js","fallbackUrl":null,"fallbackCondition":null,"isCoreModule":true},{"identifier":"LoaderFixes","url":"/_static/tfs/M172_20200708.14/_scripts/TFS/post-loader-shim.min.js","fallbackUrl":null,"fallbackCondition":null,"isCoreModule":false}],"coreScriptsBundle":{"identifier":"CoreBundle","url":"/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-basejs-v9GpWWBnsWqhM23ijhK2HfAqLowTXGUqZLDRsBCZbkfY=","fallbackUrl":null,"fallbackCondition":null,"isCoreModule":true},"extensionCoreReferences":{"identifier":"CoreBundle","url":"/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-ext-core-vXmFrbZVv9in776dlqjrJLCGMci5PQIF14Ug3E2n2Ku0=","fallbackUrl":null,"fallbackCondition":null,"isCoreModule":true}},"webAccessConfiguration":{"isHosted":true,"paths":{"rootPath":"/","staticContentRootPath":"/","staticContentVersion":"M172_20200708.14","resourcesPath":"/_static/tfs/M172_20200708.14/_content/","staticRootTfs":"/_static/tfs/M172_20200708.14/","cdnFallbackStaticRootTfs":"/_static/tfs/M172_20200708.14/","staticRoot3rdParty":"/_static/3rdParty/"},"api":{"webApiVersion":"1","areaPrefix":"_","controllerPrefix":""},"mailSettings":{"enabled":false},"registryItems":{}},"microsoftAjaxConfig":{"cultureInfo":{"name":"en-US","numberFormat":{"CurrencyDecimalDigits":2,"CurrencyDecimalSeparator":".","IsReadOnly":true,"CurrencyGroupSizes":[3],"NumberGroupSizes":[3],"PercentGroupSizes":[3],"CurrencyGroupSeparator":",","CurrencySymbol":"$","NaNSymbol":"NaN","CurrencyNegativePattern":0,"NumberNegativePattern":1,"PercentPositivePattern":1,"PercentNegativePattern":1,"NegativeInfinitySymbol":"-∞","NegativeSign":"-","NumberDecimalDigits":2,"NumberDecimalSeparator":".","NumberGroupSeparator":",","CurrencyPositivePattern":0,"PositiveInfinitySymbol":"∞","PositiveSign":"+","PercentDecimalDigits":2,"PercentDecimalSeparator":".","PercentGroupSeparator":",","PercentSymbol":"%","PerMilleSymbol":"‰","NativeDigits":["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"],"DigitSubstitution":1},"dateTimeFormat":{"AMDesignator":"AM","Calendar":{"MinSupportedDateTime":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","MaxSupportedDateTime":"9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999","AlgorithmType":1,"CalendarType":1,"Eras":[1],"TwoDigitYearMax":2029,"IsReadOnly":true},"DateSeparator":"/","FirstDayOfWeek":0,"CalendarWeekRule":0,"FullDateTimePattern":"dddd, MMMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss tt","LongDatePattern":"dddd, MMMM d, yyyy","LongTimePattern":"h:mm:ss tt","MonthDayPattern":"MMMM d","PMDesignator":"PM","RFC1123Pattern":"ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'","ShortDatePattern":"M/d/yyyy","ShortTimePattern":"h:mm tt","SortableDateTimePattern":"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss","TimeSeparator":":","UniversalSortableDateTimePattern":"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z'","YearMonthPattern":"MMMM yyyy","AbbreviatedDayNames":["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"],"ShortestDayNames":["Su","Mo","Tu","We","Th","Fr","Sa"],"DayNames":["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"],"AbbreviatedMonthNames":["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec",""],"MonthNames":["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December",""],"IsReadOnly":true,"NativeCalendarName":"Gregorian Calendar","AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames":["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec",""],"MonthGenitiveNames":["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December",""]},"numberShortForm":{"QuantitySymbols":["K","M","B"],"NumberGroupSize":1000,"ThousandSymbol":"K"},"eras":null}},"timeZonesConfiguration":{},"featureAvailability":{"featureStates":{"VisualStudio.Services.Contribution.EnableOnPremUnsecureBrowsers":false,"VisualStudio.Service.WebPlatform.ClientErrorReporting":false,"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Gallery.Client.UseCdnAssetUri":false,"VisualStudio.Services.WebAccess.SubresourceIntegrity":false,"VisualStudio.Services.IdentityPicker.ReactProfileCard":true}},"appInsightsConfiguration":{"enabled":false,"instrumentationKey":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","insightsScriptUrl":null},"diagnostics":{"sessionId":"f6a1e2ac-a812-49e0-9d52-d7ee7f8143d0","activityId":"f6a1e2ac-a812-49e0-9d52-d7ee7f8143d0","bundlingEnabled":true,"webPlatformVersion":"M172","serviceVersion":"Dev18.M172.1 (build: AzureDevOps_M172_20200708.14)"},"navigation":{"topMostLevel":"deployment","area":"","currentController":"Signin","currentAction":"Index","routeId":"LegacyWebAccessRoute","routeValues":{"controller":"Signin","action":"Index"}},"globalization":{"explicitTheme":"","theme":"Default","culture":"en-US","timezoneOffset":0,"timeZoneId":"UTC"},"serviceInstanceId":"951917ac-a960-4999-8464-e3f0aa25b381","hubsContext":{},"serviceLocations":{"locations":{"951917ac-a960-4999-8464-e3f0aa25b381":{"Application":"https://spsprodweu4.vssps.visualstudio.com/","Deployment":"https://spsprodweu4.vssps.visualstudio.com/"}}}};</script><script type="text/javascript"> var __cultureInfo = __vssPageContext.microsoftAjaxConfig.cultureInfo;</script>
<script type="text/javascript">if (window.performance && window.performance.mark) { window.performance.mark('startLoadBundleOuter-basejs'); }</script>
<script data-bundlelength="125076" data-bundlename="basejs" src="/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-basejs-v9GpWWBnsWqhM23ijhK2HfAqLowTXGUqZLDRsBCZbkfY=" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">if (window.performance && window.performance.mark) { window.performance.mark('endLoadBundleOuter-basejs'); }</script>


<script type="text/javascript"> require.config(__vssPageContext.moduleLoaderConfig);</script>

    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="NczcE2VqtZurcha-i70MYWJmzvklYWzgZmMOD4_U9KGkpElkwsliaVLxrc5SUWZXGi0kzpaOtqckBS6JZEDleh7ctQA1" /><input name="__RequestVerificationToken2" type="hidden" value="__RequestVerificationToken209a26724-ac5a-4587-887f-60eb94fca407" />
    
    


    
    
    <div class="account signin main-container hide">


            <div class="page-content">
                <div class="header-section" role="banner">
                    

                    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_static/tfs/M172_20200708.14/_content/Combined.css">
                    <div id="ux-header" class="FF ltr vsIntegrate" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                        <span id="isMobile"></span>
                        <div class="upperBand">
                            <div class="upperBandContent">
                                <div class="left"></div>
                                <div class="right">
                                    <div class="profileImage"></div>

                                    <div id="signIn">
                                        <a class=":SignedOutProfileElement: createProfileLink" href="/go/profile" title="Anonymous">Anonymous</a>
                                        <a class="scarabLink" href="/_signout">Sign out</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="clear-both"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content-section" role="main">
                    
    
            <div class="signin-main-content">
                <noscript>
                    <span class="error">Microsoft Internet Explorer&#39;s Enhanced Security Configuration is currently enabled on your environment. This enhanced level of security prevents our web integration experiences from displaying or performing correctly. To continue with your operation please disable this configuration or contact your administrator.</span>
                </noscript>
                <div class="provider-control">                    
                    <script class="options" defer="defer" type="application/json">{"providerOptions":{"force":false,"orgIdAuthUrl":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/c627bf07-e774-48cd-9e33-eeeed30d747b/oauth2/authorize?client_id=499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798\u0026site_id=501454\u0026response_mode=form_post\u0026response_type=code+id_token\u0026redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fspsprodweu4.vssps.visualstudio.com%2F_signedin\u0026nonce=15b49048-8f5c-43a8-8e2d-77067ccdbc15\u0026state=realm%3Ddev.azure.com%26reply_to%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fdev.azure.com%252FOrgnatinTest%252FAIProject%252F_apis%252Fgit%252Frepositories%252Fe9e2f082-6f6d-4cfd-a7af-869b0bcc737a%252Fitems%253Fpath%253D%25252FV4.1.0.0%25252FDB%25252FDWH%25252FDWH%25252FDWH%25252FAMF.sql%2526includeContent%253Dtrue%2526api-version%253D5.1%26ht%3D2%26hid%3D750bf9a1-4ded-4c22-89dd-a2740fccd529%26nonce%3D15b49048-8f5c-43a8-8e2d-77067ccdbc15\u0026resource=https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.core.windows.net%2F\u0026cid=15b49048-8f5c-43a8-8e2d-77067ccdbc15\u0026wsucxt=1","user":null,"signInContext":"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"}}</script>
                </div>
            </div>


                </div>
                 
    
    </div>


    
    

    <script type="text/javascript">if (window.performance && window.performance.mark) { window.performance.mark('startLoadBundleOuter-common'); }</script>
<script data-bundlelength="205378" data-bundlename="common" data-includedscripts="VSS/Bundling" src="/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-common-v_Ss9wqVqy_aJagjjTroIfzbnjzMUeKzN0KlnLkpPbLw=" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">if (window.performance && window.performance.mark) { window.performance.mark('endLoadBundleOuter-common'); }</script>
<script type="text/javascript">if (window.performance && window.performance.mark) { window.performance.mark('startLoadBundleOuter-view'); }</script>
<script data-bundlelength="157426" data-bundlename="view" data-includedscripts="Authentication/Scripts/SPS.Authentication.Controls;Authentication/Scripts/SPS.Authentication" src="/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-view-vip8jjFGoJo8AL2ac18TvWQ8inaN47zLqW97-Gn61kAs=" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">if (window.performance && window.performance.mark) { window.performance.mark('endLoadBundleOuter-view'); }</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> if (window.performance && window.performance.mark) { window.performance.mark('requireStart'); }
require(["Authentication/Scripts/SPS.Authentication.Controls","Authentication/Scripts/SPS.Authentication"], function(){  if (window.performance && window.performance.mark) { window.performance.mark('requireEnd'); } window.requiredModulesLoaded=true;  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried to download from downlink. I am facing the same issue. Should we add authorization to the application on development in Azure DevOps server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found solution to this issue.Here we are trying to use Personal access token(PAT).In order to use PAT for authentication we have to use authorization as `"Basic"` instead of `"Bearer"`.More over instead of adding PAT alone to the Request header we have to use **combination of username and PAT**.Say base-64-encoded-string of username:PAT.

**Required Code Change**

```
var personalaccesstoken = "wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwy47b7ugkz32bubi64bw7fqdyfpa";
 var base64Creds = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("SPabbbal@ABCTech.com:"+ personalaccesstoken));
request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Basic " + base64Creds);
```

thank you for support.

Answer (score 0):

Your PAT token is your username+password with scopes (permissions) applied. So when calling with the bearer token, the syntax for the token is a Base64 encoded string of the username:token. Because the token represents the user, the username isn’t specified, so you specify an empty string instead.

From: [Use a PAT in your code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#use-a-pat-in-your-code)

```
public static async void GetBuilds()
{
    try
    {
        var personalaccesstoken = "PATFROMWEB";

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                Convert.ToBase64String(
                    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                        string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", personalaccesstoken))));

            using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(
                        "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.0").Result)
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```